# Is there any way to inset only a1 to a10 outputs into table table in one iteration?

Tags: scala, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is my code. I get all output of result from `a1` to `a10`... I want add only that 10 value in the total... But there is problem of multiple entries whenever I use insert query. Is there any way to insert only `a1` to `a10` outputs into table `table` in one iteration?

I want insert all values from `a1` to `a10` in this table

```
for (r <- result) {
  val l = SQL(
    """
          insert into total (e1, e2, e3.....) values (
   {e1},{e2},{e3}......)
      """)(
    'e1-> r.e1,
    'e2 -> r.e2,
    'e3 -> r.e3)
}
}
a1 = b1         // i got all the output addition here.
a2 = b2
a3 = b3
a4 = b4
a5 = b5
//.
//.
//.
//.
a10 = b10
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some additional details to the code. Is SQL `anorm` SQL by any chance ? What is a1 and b1 ?

Comment: b1 is addition of e3 on each entry... and value of each phase of b1 is past to the a1,a2...and so on.

Comment: Your question is still not clear to me. Please show the import statements. Some sample input and sample output, so that I can replicate your problem on my machine, if needed.